# How to print remaining items in list?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am trying to print the remaining items in a list.

I want to ask the user to input where he is: Utrecht(this is for example item 5, if it matches print the remaining stops in the list (like: okay, item 6, item 7 etc. are the remaining stops). I tried with slicing but it is not what i really want or maybe i tried wrong. Which function can i use for this?

Got this so far:

```
station = ['Utrecht', 'Amsterdam', 'Zwolle', 'Groningen','Leeuwarden']

vraag = input("Where are you?")
while station == vraag:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, check if the value exist in the list, if succeed find the index.

And finally, as list index is inclusive before ":", you should use (value+1)

```
try:
    print station[station.index(vraag)+1:]
except ValueError:
    print "Not in the list"
```

Though i haven't used 3.4.3,In python 3.4, you can iterate this with a normal for loop as it returns a generator.

```
lst = station[station.index(vraag)+1:]
for i in lst:
    print i,
```

How to do end check:

```
if lst == []:
    print "end"
```

Comment: I get this?
Where are you? Amsterdam
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x005093A0>

Comment: which problem you facing?

Comment: i i type for example Amsterdam en hit enter i see this: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x005093A0>

Comment: would you plz update your question with the code you tried? it should work

Answer (score 1):

```
location = input("Where are you? ")
try:
    if len(station[station.index(location)+1:]) == 0:
        print('This is the end.')
    print(' -> '.join(station[station.index(location)+1:]))
except ValueError:
    print('Check your location.')
```

Output:

```
location = 'Amsterdam'
'Zwolle -> Groningen -> Leeuwarden'
```

Comment: use print(' -> '.join(station[station.index(location)+1:]]))

Comment: there was a ] too much but thanks!! i have 2 questions: I want to say after user input: Current station is: Utrecht
the remaining stops are: Amsterdam,Zwolle etc. but if you are in Leeuwarden i want to print This is the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Just find the index from user input and use slicing

```
loc=input("Where are you?")
try:
    idx=station.index(loc)
    print(station[idx+1:])
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: This will print  list including the matched one, which is not desired.